# How to add sudo user on solaris?

Tags: linux, solaris, sudo

I am using Solaris 11 , I have added user to sudo user file ( /etc/sudoers) , still its prompting for password.

```
arcsys@solaris:~$ sudo -l
User arcsys may run the following commands on solaris:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/cat
    (ALL) ALL
arcsys@solaris:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
Password:
```

I am not able to understand that what is wrong here?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

The command you need to execute is:

```
sudo /usr/bin/cat /etc/sudoers
```

`sudo` is strict when you have configured the full path to the program(s)

Answer (score 0):

As root, run:

visudo

and check to make sure your username is added

root      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

arcsys    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Save, and quit, then run:

sudo "command"

The system will prompt you for YOUR password. If you have the proper access, it will run. If not, you will need to run visudo either as root, or by running sudo visudo.

Comment: As you can see from the question OP have already records in `sudoers`. And the problem is in format of `sudo` command. I do not see any value in your answer.